# SOAP requests are blocking other SOAP requests

Tags: php, wcf, soap, soap-client

I have a WordPress web application which communicates to a WCF service through SOAP.

Let's say I access a long running SOAP request. In another tab, I access another SOAP request, but this one is short running. The short request seems to get blocked by the long running one.

When doing SOAP requests, I create a new client for every request. I don't know the details of the configuration of the WCF Service, but I'm sure it's capable of processing concurrent requests. This is because when running *another instance* of the web application, other short requests finishes without waiting for the long running one in the first instance of the web application.

I've looked into using some kind of async SOAP Client, but I haven't found anything that works for me. Since I find so little information around this, I'm thinking I may be the one that's doing something wrong.

Why does running requests block other requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have to do with WCF. Your PHP session file is being locked, so you can only have one concurrent request per browser.

There are basically two solutions:

- Start the WCF call in a background thread or background process on your web server. This way the PHP script handling the browser request can return immediately.
- Change the WCF service so instead of executing immediately, it accepts a "Start Working" call and you can poll for the result of the execution.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to run calls on a background thread? Any resources that might help me to achieve this? I've never ran WCF calls on a background thread before.

Comment: No, I meant starting the long-running WCF call _from_ PHP on another thread, so the script continues its execution and returns a response to the browser. You'll then have to store the result in a database or whatever, so the client can be notified (or poll for) when the WCF call completes.

Comment: The long running request will only be run through a REST API (in the same instance of PHP) I've provided. Is it possible to separate this and let the regular webpage not be locked by the PHP session file?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but my PHP knowledge is not up-to-date enough to recommend an approach. Try searching for something like "php start background job". You could for example start a `exec("wget ...")` where you call a PHP script on the same site.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood the reality of this problem. I thought this problem would affect **multiple users**. I tried this with different browser, and the lock is not happening anymore, as you said. The session file lock is probably tied to a specific user, and would actually make sense.

Comment: That's right, it's per user. Or rather, per browser.